# Find the minimum number of operations required to compute a number using a specified range of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

Let me start with an example - 
I have a range of numbers from 1 to 9. And let's say the target number that I want is 29.
In this case the minimum number of operations that are required would be (9*3)+2 = 2 operations. Similarly for 18 the minimum number of operations is 1 (9*2=18).
I can use any of the 4 arithmetic operators - +, -, / and *.

How can I programmatically find out the minimum number of operations required?
Thanks in advance for any help provided.

clarification: <del>integers only, no decimals allowed mid-calculation. i.e. the following is not valid (from comments below): ((**9/2**) + 1) * 4 == 22</del>
I must admit I didn't think about this thoroughly, but for my purpose it doesn't matter if decimal numbers appear mid-calculation. ((9/2) + 1) * 4 == 22 is valid. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: there is a trivial backtracking solution, but it is exponential. Do you have time complexity constraint?

Comment: @KennyTM - tnx. I should have used a better example.

Comment: @amit - no time complexity constraint.

Comment: Integer arithmetic only, I suppose? i.e. what about ((9/2) + 1) * 4 == 22 ? Is the 9/2 allowed? Clarify in question.

Comment: +1 for just talking about this earlier today.

Comment: Do you get to reuse numbers? Can 81 be 9*9, or must I add two numbers to get the second 9?

Comment: Firstly, are braces allowed or not? It is not clear from your examples. In all valid examples the braces are redundant. The only example with non-redundant braces is invalid. So, are braces allowed or not?

Comment: Secondly, what does "integers only" mean exactly? Does that mean that `9/2` is completely prohibited? Or does it mean that `9/2` is assumed to be `4` instead of `4.5`?

Comment: @AndreyT - braces are allowed. Also, braces were necessary in the first example (9*3)+2 != 9*(3+2).

Comment: @Bookamp: Well, under the standard definition of arithmetic notation, `9*3+2` is already defined as equivalent to `(9*3)+2`, so your braces are superfluous.

Comment: @ccoakley Yes, you can reuse numbers

Comment: @Bookamp: Then cyborg's answer is a good starting point, since you don't need to check if a number has already been used. Best to arrange in RPN (or some stack form), though, so that parens don't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the special case where set Y = [1..9] and n > 0:

- n <= 9 : 0 operations
- n <=18 : 1 operation (+)
- otherwise : Remove any divisor found in Y. If this is not enough, do a recursion on the remainder for all offsets -9 .. +9. Offset 0 can be skipped as it has already been tried.

Notice how division is not needed in this case. For other Y this does not hold.

This algorithm is exponential in log(n). The exact analysis is a job for somebody with more knowledge about algebra than I.

For more speed, add pruning to eliminate some of the search for larger numbers.

Sample code:

```
def findop(n, maxlen=9999):
    # Return a short postfix list of numbers and operations

    # Simple solution to small numbers
    if n<=9: return [n]
    if n<=18: return [9,n-9,'+']

    # Find direct multiply
    x = divlist(n)
    if len(x) > 1:
        mults = len(x)-1
        x[-1:] = findop(x[-1], maxlen-2*mults)
        x.extend(['*'] * mults)
        return x

    shortest = 0

    for o in range(1,10) + range(-1,-10,-1):
        x = divlist(n-o)
        if len(x) == 1: continue
        mults = len(x)-1

        # We spent len(divlist) + mults + 2 fields for offset. 
        # The last number is expanded by the recursion, so it doesn't count. 
        recursion_maxlen = maxlen - len(x) - mults - 2 + 1

        if recursion_maxlen < 1: continue
        x[-1:] = findop(x[-1], recursion_maxlen)
        x.extend(['*'] * mults)
        if o > 0:
            x.extend([o, '+'])
        else:
            x.extend([-o, '-'])
        if shortest == 0 or len(x) < shortest:
            shortest = len(x)
            maxlen = shortest - 1
            solution = x[:]

    if shortest == 0:
        # Fake solution, it will be discarded
        return '#' * (maxlen+1)
    return solution

def divlist(n):
    l = []
    for d in range(9,1,-1):
        while n%d == 0:
            l.append(d)
            n = n/d
    if n>1: l.append(n)
    return l
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to test all possibilities with `k` operations, for `k` starting from `0`. Imagine you create a tree of height `k` that branches for every possible new operation with operand (4*9 branches per level). You need to traverse and evaluate the *leaves* of the tree for each `k` before moving to the next `k`.

I didn't test this pseudo-code:

```
for every k from 0 to infinity
  for every n from 1 to 9
    if compute(n,0,k):
      return k


boolean compute(n,j,k):
  if (j == k):
    return (n == target)
  else:
    for each operator in {+,-,*,/}:
       for every i from 1 to 9:
         if compute((n operator i),j+1,k):
           return true
    return false
```

It doesn't take into account arithmetic operators precedence and braces, that would require some rework.

Comment: Screw infix. Use a stack. Paren and operator precedence don't matter, and you can translate back for the final answer. This technique is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Really cool question :)

Notice that you can start from the end! From your example (9*3)+2 = 29 is equivalent to saying (29-2)/3=9. That way we can avoid the double loop in cyborg's answer. This suggests the following algorithm for set `Y` and result `r`:

```
nextleaves = {r}
nops = 0
while(true):
   nops = nops+1
   leaves = nextleaves
   nextleaves = {}
   for leaf in leaves:
      for y in Y:
         if (leaf+y) or (leaf-y) or (leaf*y) or (leaf/y) is in X:
             return(nops)
         else:
             add (leaf+y) and (leaf-y) and (leaf*y) and (leaf/y) to nextleaves
```

This is the basic idea, performance can be certainly be improved, for instance by avoiding "backtracks", such as `r+a-a` or `r*a*b/a`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my idea is similar to the one of Peer Sommerlund:

For big numbers, you advance fast, by multiplication with big ciphers.

Is Y=29 prime? If not, divide it by the maximum divider of (2 to 9).
Else you could subtract a number, to reach a dividable number. 27 is fine, since it is dividable by 9, so

```
(29-2)/9=3 => 
3*9+2 = 29
```

So maybe - I didn't think about this to the end: Search the next divisible by 9 number below Y. If you don't reach a number which is a digit, repeat.

The formula is the steps reversed.

(I'll try it for some numbers. :) )

I tried with 2551, which is

```
echo $((((3*9+4)*9+4)*9+4))
```

But I didn't test every intermediate result whether it is prime.
But

```
echo $((8*8*8*5-9))
```

is 2 operations less. Maybe I can investigate this later.